# How to make createTextRange work based on my example?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I wrote functionality to replace text when user types into a text field. I wrote separately for chrome firefox safari and opera. I wrote for newer IE-s, however I could not modify it to fit IE8. Please help me make it work for that environment. I don't look for IE7 now at all because it's so probelematic, but I need it for IE8.

```
if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
          var selectionRange = document.selection.createRange();
          var textInputRange = element.createTextRange();
          var precedingRange = element.createTextRange();
          var bookmark = selectionRange.getBookmark();
          textInputRange.moveToBookmark(bookmark);
          precedingRange.setEndPoint('EndToStart', textInputRange);
          start = precedingRange.text.length;
          end = start + selectionRange.text.length;

          element.value = val.slice(0, start) + 'WORKS' + val.slice(end);
          start++;

          textInputRange = element.createTextRange();
          textInputRange.collapse(true);
          textInputRange.move('character', start - (element.value.slice(0, start).split("\r\n").length - 1));
          textInputRange.select();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also wrote code for a such purposes and I used rangy framework (https://code.google.com/p/rangy/). It helps very much! It has the following function (piece from wiki: https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/TextRangeModule):

```
pasteHtml(String html)
Replaces the contents of the range with HTML specified by html.
```

It's easy to use and powerful.